# How to split columns in data frame by semicolon in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

My question feels to me too obvious, however, I could not find a solution.

a have a data frame like this:

```
<TICKER>;<PER>;<DATE>;<TIME>;<OPEN>;<HIGH>;<LOW>;<CLOSE>
USD Index;D;20150801;000000;97.199;97.336;97.191;97.192
USD Index;D;20150802;000000;97.226;97.294;97.207;97.257
USD Index;D;20150803;000000;97.255;97.582;97.155;97.499
```

I need them split in different columns by ; like this:

```
<TICKER>    <PER>   <DATE>  <TIME>  <OPEN>  <HIGH>  <LOW>   <CLOSE>
USD Index   D   20150801    0   97.199  97.336  97.191  97.192
USD Index   D   20150802    0   97.226  97.294  97.207  97.257
USD Index   D   20150803    0   97.255  97.582  97.155  97.499
```

This is a basic question that needs to be at the top of search results. Thank you in advance for helping me to resolve this issue!

Comment: do you have a file like this or a character vector? or a single column data frame?

Comment: I have a single column data frame. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `read.table`

```
setNames(read.table(text=dat[,1], sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
           scan(text=names(dat), sep=";", what = "", quiet = TRUE))
#    <TICKER> <PER>   <DATE> <TIME> <OPEN> <HIGH>  <LOW> <CLOSE>
# 1 USD Index     D 20150801      0 97.199 97.336 97.191  97.192
# 2 USD Index     D 20150802      0 97.226 97.294 97.207  97.257
# 3 USD Index     D 20150803      0 97.255 97.582 97.155  97.499
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(`<TICKER>;<PER>;<DATE>;<TIME>;<OPEN>;<HIGH>;<LOW>;<CLOSE>` =
 c("USD Index;D;20150801;000000;97.199;97.336;97.191;97.192", 
"USD Index;D;20150802;000000;97.226;97.294;97.207;97.257", 
"USD Index;D;20150803;000000;97.255;97.582;97.155;97.499"
 )), .Names = "<TICKER>;<PER>;<DATE>;<TIME>;<OPEN>;<HIGH>;<LOW>;<CLOSE>", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely easy with `fread()`.  Using akrun's `dat`, we have

```
data.table::fread(paste(c(names(dat), dat[[1]]), collapse = "\n"))
#     <TICKER> <PER>   <DATE> <TIME> <OPEN> <HIGH>  <LOW> <CLOSE>
# 1: USD Index     D 20150801      0 97.199 97.336 97.191  97.192
# 2: USD Index     D 20150802      0 97.226 97.294 97.207  97.257
# 3: USD Index     D 20150803      0 97.255 97.582 97.155  97.499
```

For a data frame result, simply add `data.table = FALSE` in the `fread()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, `tstrsplit()` can be used to split into columns and `setnames()` to rename the columns:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, tstrsplit(.SD[[1]], ";")][, setnames(.SD, strsplit(names(dat), ";")[[1]])]
```

> ```
>     <TICKER> <PER>   <DATE> <TIME> <OPEN> <HIGH>  <LOW> <CLOSE>
> 1: USD Index     D 20150801 000000 97.199 97.336 97.191  97.192
> 2: USD Index     D 20150802 000000 97.226 97.294 97.207  97.257
> 3: USD Index     D 20150803 000000 97.255 97.582 97.155  97.499
> ```

Note that `<TICKER>`, etc. are *not* syntactically valid column names which need to be escaped in many places. Therfore, I suggest to get rid of the angle brackets like this:

```
setDT(dat)[, tstrsplit(.SD[[1]], ";")][
  , setnames(.SD, gsub("[<>]", "", strsplit(names(dat), ";")[[1]]))]
```

> ```
>       TICKER PER     DATE   TIME   OPEN   HIGH    LOW  CLOSE
> 1: USD Index   D 20150801 000000 97.199 97.336 97.191 97.192
> 2: USD Index   D 20150802 000000 97.226 97.294 97.207 97.257
> 3: USD Index   D 20150803 000000 97.255 97.582 97.155 97.499
> ```